# Control TV using Xamarin Forms (HDMI CEC)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hi im building a app in Xamarin Forms for the Amazon Fire TV Stick. The App should be able to turn the TV on and off which is connected to the Fire TV Stick. My idea was to do it using HDMI CEC but i was not finding a solution how to do such. I would appreciate getting a name to something like a NUGET Package i could use or even better code snips which demonstrate how it works.

I was searching for answers in the web without any solution that could solve my problem.
And using Java is not a possible solution.